# Not able to run Azure Data Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to implement my first MLOps on Microsoft Azure. I am following their official document here:

[MlOps using Azure ML and Azure pipelines](https://benalexkeen.com/creating-end-to-end-mlops-pipelines-using-azure-ml-and-azure-pipelines-part-3/)

I have followed all their steps till Data pipeline. When I try to run the data-pipeline, I get the following error:

`No plan found for identifier 3b6fd8bf-2fc0-4739-9a93-7e1210e45ae8.`

Attaching a screenshot of the same.

[image]

I have just started with MLOps and Azure DevOps. I will glad if someone can help.